# How to acess my stacks from routes.js in App.js

Tags: react-native

How can i use **AppContainer** in my main file **App.js**? And navigate between pages of these two stacks **AuthenticationNavigator** and **MainNavigator**
I'm trying to acess my stacks from **routes.js** in the **App.js**, but i cant. Can someone tell me what's wrong in the code?

> routes.js

```js
const AuthenticationNavigator  = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Login',
        headerShown: false, //desabilita a barra do topo
      },
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Cadastro',
      },
    },
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTintColor: '#FFF',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#121212',
      },
    }
})

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Main',
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Main',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    headerTintColor: '#FFF',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#121212',
    },
  }
})

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  /*
   * Rather than being rendered by a screen component, the
   * AuthenticationNavigator is a screen component
   */
  Auth: AuthenticationNavigator,
  Home: MainNavigator,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Auth'}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer
```

The way it's imported in **App.js**

```js
import AppContainer from "./src/routes"
```

> Where and how i try to acess the stacks(**App.js**):

```js
render() {
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticationReady) {
      return (
        {}
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#121212" />
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <AppContainer /> : <AppContainer />}
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you have to use `this.props.navigation.navigate("MainScreen")` for this to work. I would do it inside of ComponentDidMount() function. Everything else looks good.

Comment: you need to export ```InitialStack```, ```MainStack```, ```Loading``` before import. check your ```routes.js``` & make sure to export those stacks

Comment: if you want to ```import {InitialStack, MainStack, Loading} from "./src/routes"``` you have to export those separately.

Comment: But then how im supposed to do createAppContainer? @SDushan

Comment: I edited with my actual code after some research and help from others

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are exporting your all routes like

```
export  {InitialStack, MainStack, Loading}
```

because you want to use it as

```
import {InitialStack, MainStack, Loading} from "./src/routes"
```

And you need to add state in your this line

```
 {this.isAuthenticated ? <MainStack /> : <InitialStack />} // change this to 

 {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <MainStack /> : <InitialStack />}
```

Comment: but then where im suppose to use the createAppContainer()? Don't i need it?

Comment: I did this and now i get the **error**: "The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly."

Comment: i edited with my actual code after some research and help from others

Comment: try to learn more about navigation here is small example how to use switch navigation first try this small example then implement it with your project : https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3